# How can I disable a Widows 7/8.1/10 shortcut key WITHOUT disabling ALL shortcut keys?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

Has anyone ever encountered a program or a registry hack that will either allow you to disable particular Windows shortcut keys, or maybe remap them?

I am not really interested in methods to disable ALL shortcuts, as I want to be able to still use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> shortcuts, but disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> shortcut which undoes the previous action. This has been very problematic to me as I often copy large amounts of files, and sometimes accidentally undo a copy. When this happens, there is really no indication of it, no message pops up and there isn't even a file copy dialog window, the "undo" operation happens entirely in the background. So when I finish copying files, I will sometimes then end up deleting some of them because they were moved back to the original folder without my knowledge. I also almost always use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> out of habit, so I can't just look in the Recycle Bin.

If anyone has a solution, thank you in advance! I have been struggling to find one for a while now. :(

Comment: Ok I admit it's a joke: don't press CTRL+z then. But to be a bit more helpful, what is it which actually makes you use the combination. If you can't reconfigure the explorer, maybe you can reconfigure the real place where you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardware work-around: put a bit of plastic foam under the <kbd>Z</kbd> key to make it a bit harder to press, so you'll get tactile feedback. This helped curb my habit of hitting <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> accidentally.

Though I wouldn't suggest this approach for a more frequently used key, in most languages *(other than polszczyznę ;-)*, you don't hit <kbd>Z</kbd> often.

Comment: @Braden'sPC's – I am sorry I flagged your comments for language. If I may ask you please [be nice](https://superuser.com/help/be-nice) on all [se] network sites.

Comment: @miroxlav just noticed this. Sorry if I offended anyone, just trying to thank mr DrMoishe Pippik for a job well done.

Answer (score 2):

You already accepted an answer, but you can use [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com) to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

The script is super simple:

```
^z::
```

Thats it...  It remaps <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to nothing, thereby doing nothing

Comment: FYI you can do this with the caps lock key as well ::)

Comment: I love this solution too! I've used AHK for gaming macros in the past, but then I got a proper gaming keyboard and mouse and stopped using it. I didn't think about all the other uses for it. Thanks!